# Notifying ViewModel that Model Collection changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a model collection that is referenced from a most parts of my code.

```
public class TraceEntryQueue
    {
        private readonly Queue<TraceEntry> _logEntries; 

        public TraceEntryQueue()
        {
            _logEntries = new Queue<TraceEntry>();
        }

        public void AddEntry(TraceEntry newEntry)
        {
            _logEntries.Enqueue(newEntry);

        }

        public List<TraceEntry> GetAsList()
        {
            return _logEntries.ToList();
        }
    }
```

This collection is presented  in one of my views.

```
public class LoggingViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ICollectionView _customers;
        public ICollectionView Customers
        {
            get
            {
                return _customers;
            }
            private set
            {
                _customers = value;

            }
        }

        public LoggingViewModel(TraceEntryQueue traceQueue)
        {

            Customers = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(traceQueue.GetAsList());
            Customers.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Index", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            Customers.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The question is how I can notify my view to reload the collection when I add new entries via

```
            public void AddEntry(TraceEntry newEntry)
            {
                _logEntries.Enqueue(newEntry);

            }
```

Comment: You can publish the event from domain and capture it in GUI. See the [link](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/)

Comment: I thought somehow to raise events from the viewModel and not from the model itself.

Comment: you can use IEventAggrgator to raise the event just after adding the entry in collection. but this is possible only if you are firing AddEntry from any view model only.

Comment: Have you thought about using an ObservableCollection instead of a queue?

Comment: @RobJohnson could you give me an example, how this can work

Comment: @NightWalker see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an observable collection instead of a queue.  This will automatically notify your view when the collection is updated (add/remove etc.)

```
public class TraceEntryQueue
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TraceEntry> _logEntries; 

    public TraceEntryQueue()
    {
        _logEntries = new ObservableCollection<TraceEntry>();
    }

    public void AddEntry(TraceEntry newEntry)
    {
        _logEntries.Add(newEntry);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TraceEntry> GetLogEntries()
    {
        return _logEntries;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TraceEntryQueue
{
    private readonly Queue<TraceEntry> _logEntries; 
    private readonly ICollectionView _logEntriesView; 

    public TraceEntryQueue()
    {
        _logEntries = new Queue<TraceEntry>();
        _logEntriesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(logEntries.ToList());
    }

    //....

    public void AddEntry(TraceEntry newEntry)
    {
        _logEntries.Enqueue(newEntry);
        _logEntriesView.SourceCollection = logEntries.ToList();
        _logEntriesView.Refresh();
    }

    public ICollectionView GetAsView()
    {
        return _logEntriesView;
    }
}
```

Use `GetAsView` and bind directly to your datagrid / listbox / listview.

Answer (score 0):

As @RobJohnson mentionned, you can use an ObservableCollection. However, if you need to create your own collection class, you should implement the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interface:

```
public class TraceEntryQueue : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private readonly Queue<TraceEntry> _logEntries;

    public TraceEntryQueue()
    {
        _logEntries = new Queue<TraceEntry>();
    }

    public void AddEntry(TraceEntry newEntry)
    {
        _logEntries.Enqueue(newEntry);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newEntry));
    }

    public List<TraceEntry> GetAsList()
    {
        return _logEntries.ToList();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```